# Reference a subnode with html_nodes

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I would like to extract the number of pages of a website, the number is inside a nested node.

my website is https://www.cbanque.com/pratique/agences/credit-mutuel/33/

When I do

```
soup=read_html(page1)

 soup%>%html_nodes("div.col-xs-4)
```

I get

```
[1] <div class="col-xs-4"> </div>\n
[2] <div class="col-xs-4 tcenter">64 agences - Page 1 / 6</div>\n
[3] <div class="col-xs-4 tright"><a href="/pratique/agences/credit-mutuel/33/2/" class=" ...
[4] <div class="col-xs-4"> </div>\n
[5] <div class="col-xs-4 tcenter">64 agences - Page 1 / 6</div>\n
[6] <div class="col-xs-4 tright"><a href="/pratique/agences/credit-mutuel/33/2/" class=" ...
[7] <div class="col-xs-4">\n\t\t\t<span class="icon-cbanque"></span>\n\t\t</div>
[8] <div class="col-xs-4"> </div>
[9] <div class="col-xs-4 reseau-soc">\n\t\t\tSuivez-nous aussi sur\n\t\t\t<ul class="lis ...
```

I would like to acces the node called  "col-xs-4 tcenter", and the value inside it.

Comment: How about `soup %>%
  html_nodes("div.col-xs-4") %>%
  html_text() %>%
  .[2]` ? would it work?

Comment: Probably yes, but I would like to get it using the  "col-xs-4 tcenter" tag,

Answer (score 0):

You could use str_split

```
library(rvest))
library(magrittr)

page <- read_html("https://www.cbanque.com/pratique/agences/credit-mutuel/33/")
s <- page %>% html_node(".col-xs-4.tcenter") %>% html_text()
x <- strsplit(s, "/ ", fixed=FALSE)[[1]]
print(x[[-1]])
```

Or regex

```
library(rvest))
library(magrittr)
library(stringr)

page <- read_html("https://www.cbanque.com/pratique/agences/credit-mutuel/33/")
s <- page %>% html_node(".col-xs-4.tcenter") %>% html_text()
x <- str_match_all(s ,'/\\s+(\\d+)')
print(x[[1]][,2])
```